# Datatables.net | table id=tbl_portfolio - Invalid JSON response

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatables

this is my first question on stackoverflow.com:
I've found many answers here in the past, but now i have a problem which i can't solve:
I have a project where i use the DataTables jquery plugin to display some data from a simple SQL db.
All worked fine, but the database has already about 18K entries, so it was very slow. I'm trying to get ajax and server side processing working, but i always get the error:
"DataTables warning: table id=tbl_portfolio - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"

I've checked the link, but i get no response, so i can't debug that way.
I read a lot and tried various things, but it's nothing is working.

Maybe it's worth to say that DataTables is running in a Wordpress child-theme.

The HTML is:

```
<table id="tbl_portfolio" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Themen</th>
        <th>Keywords</th>
        <th>Land</th>
        <th>Kennzeichnung</th>
        <th>Linkart</th>
        <th>Ek Preis</th>
        <th>Text inkl.</th>
        <th>Text Preis</th>
        <th>End Preis</th>
        <th>Anmerkungen</th>
        <th>Firma</th>
        <th>Anrede</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
        <th>Strasse</th>
        <th>Adresszusatz</th>
        <th>PLZ</th>
        <th>Ort</th>
        <th>Land</th>
        <th>eMail</th>
        <th>Telefon</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Themen</th>
        <th>Keywords</th>
        <th>Land</th>
        <th>Kennzeichnung</th>
        <th>Linkart</th>
        <th>Ek Preis</th>
        <th>Text inkl.</th>
        <th>Text Preis</th>
        <th>End Preis</th>
        <th>Anmerkungen</th>
        <th>Firma</th>
        <th>Anrede</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
        <th>Strasse</th>
        <th>Adresszusatz</th>
        <th>PLZ</th>
        <th>Ort</th>
        <th>Land</th>
        <th>eMail</th>
        <th>Telefon</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

That's the javascript part:

```
// DB table to use
$table = 'portfolio_test';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'url', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'themen', 'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'keywords', 'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'location', 'dt' => 3 ),
array( 'db' => 'kennzeichnung', 'dt' => 4 ),
array( 'db' => 'link_art', 'dt' => 5 ),
array( 'db' => 'preis_platz', 'dt' => 6 ),
array( 'db' => 'text_inkl', 'dt' => 7 ),
array( 'db' => 'preis_text', 'dt' => 8 ),
array( 'db' => 'preis_ek', 'dt' => 9 ),
array( 'db' => 'details', 'dt' => 10 ),
array( 'db' => 'firma', 'dt' => 11 ),
array( 'db' => 'anrede', 'dt' => 12 ),
array( 'db' => 'vorname', 'dt' => 13 ),
array( 'db' => 'nachname', 'dt' => 14 ),
array( 'db' => 'strasse', 'dt' => 15 ),
array( 'db' => 'adresszusatz', 'dt' => 16 ),
array( 'db' => 'plz', 'dt' => 17 ),
array( 'db' => 'ort', 'dt' => 18 ),
array( 'db' => 'land', 'dt' => 19 ),
array( 'db' => 'email', 'dt' => 20 ),
array( 'db' => 'telefon', 'dt' => 21 )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'db_adm',
'pass' => '',
'db'   => 'seo_metrics',
'host' => 'localhost:3306'
);

require 'ssp.class.php';

echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ) 
);
```

I'm using the standard ssp.class.php file from https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

Maybe I've build in some new errors while testing all different things, but i hope some of you could find the problem!

Thank you guys!

[Picture from developer console network: blank response:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTW6Z.png)

Comment: Replace `echo json_encode` with a `var_dump` of what that method call returns, call the script directly via the browser address bar, enable full & proper error reporting … and then do some _debugging_.

Comment: Hello 04FS, thank you for your very fast answer!
With var_dump i get an array as response. Look's good so far, it get's data, but i have some special characters in the database, like Ö, Ä, Ü ...
Could that cause the error?

Comment: Here is the link to the site:
https://serply.de/serverside/

Comment: Okay, i've followed what you have written ... with var_dump and a direct call of the script i saw the special chars. Made a small test dataset without them and it works fine! Thank you, that was a good step further!
Now i try to figure out where to utf8_encode in the ssp.class.php file.
Would you give me another hint to solve that?
Thank you so much! :)

Comment: The `sql_connect` method of that class doesn’t seem to allow to specify a connection charset, but I guess you could perhaps use `sql_exec` to fire a `SET NAMES …` query yourself, before calling `SSP::simple` …?

Comment: While you've answered I have found another way:
I've edited the sql_connect method

  $db = @new PDO(
    "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']}",
    $sql_details['user'],
    $sql_details['pass'],
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
    //array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
   );
  }

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem today. Here is what worked for me.
In *ssp.class.php*, replace the

```
$db = @new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']}",
            $sql_details['user'],
            $sql_details['pass'],
            array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
        );
```

with

```
$db = @new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']}",
            $sql_details['user'],
            $sql_details['pass'],
            array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8' )
        );
```